# How to send all "already" received mails to the other recipeints of each of them

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, active-directory

I would like to know how to re-forward all my received email messages to original recipients.

I did the following modification on an OU through ADModify

1) Switch the `deliverAndRedirect` attribute value from `TRUE` to `NOT SET` for all users

2) Set a recipient address for all the users by modifying the `altRecipient` attribute value

Then, all the mail sent to the whole users of the OU have been forwarded to the recipient provided as the value of `altRecipient`. I've revert the changes, but I would like to know how to 'bulk' re-transmit mails received in the meantime to their originate recipients.

As there is thousands of items, an automated solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have transaction logs from the time period when you had this weird setup in place?

Answer (score 1):

I get what you are saying, I think.

You have set an account in Exchange to be forwarded to another recipient (without delivering to the original recipient as well), that account received x number of emails, and now you have removed the forwarding and want the emails that were forwarded to be sent again to the original account...correct?

There's not a way in Exchange 2003 to do this that I'm aware of.  The Exchange transport has already processed the emails and delivered them to their final destination/mailbox/user.  The best I can suggest to you is to get into the `altRecipient` mailbox and copy/move the forwarded mail to a PST file and then export that PST file and import it into the original mailbox.  That would work well enough for thousands of emails.